# Windows Phone 8 - Map setView

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, maps

I tried to display all my GeoCoordinate-Points on my map after loading. I found out, that i can use the `setView` method of the `Map`. I used it like this:

```
delMap.SetView(LocationRectangle.CreateBoundingRectangle(viewLocations));
```

`viewLocations` is a `GeoCoordinate[]` with 6 points. But for some reasons this is not working. The map still just centers at the point which was drawn last.
I call this in the onNavigatedTo method of the page, after drawing all the points of the locations on the map.

Anyone an idea why this is not working? Or is there a better possibility to calculate the zoom factor i need to see all the points in one view after loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I called it in the onNavigatedTo-Method. I don`t really know why this is a problem, but however, after i put it in the loaded method, it worked fine.